# User profile with map

Tags: google-maps, drupal-7

I'm using Drupal 7 with the following modules to show in the user profile their location.

- Locaction
- Gmap

With these modules, a map views can be built, or the provided location node displays the "bubbles" on the map.

However, I couldn't find out how to display the location map on the user profile node itself.

There are other modules like GMap CCK Field, but this means double entering the location.

Did I miss anything, or is there any other approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the map view on the user profile node, then you will have to custom code the user profile template file and add the view to the profile page. Then this will be displayed on the website easily.

Another way to do this can be by creating a block which shows the map view and then using [Contexts](http://drupal.org/project/context) module to display this block only when the user is viewing the profile page. In the view you have to add the relation on "Author" and then you should have the filter criteria to show map of the logged-in user.

With context, you can say that "when user is on profile page X with path "www.xyz.com/user" then display the block Y in region Z."

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Thanks for your solution. As of time reasons I´ve used a differnet solution. Anyway Your suggestions seem to be good also. Thanks.